# Foreign key passing as NULL. ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am try to work on simple School management system using ASP .NET MVC 5 and SQL Server 2012 with database first approach.

The entity of student is related with an entity class, as every student would be enrolled in a class. SO have a 'Class' type variable and FK to the Classes table as attributes of my student entity.

Create View of Student has a dropdown list that shows the classes a student can be enrolled in. The dropdown is getting populated finely enough, but when the student is created and is viewed at the Index view, its class is NULL. When I checked the FK of created Students in Server Management studio, i found that the FK is being passed as NULL.

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

PS. I am new to ASP .NET and I am not using a viewmodel because the tutorial I followed didn't and also because I didn't feel the need of making one.

Here is my Student.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Student
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Student()
    {
        this.Attendences = new HashSet<Attendence>();
    }

    public int St_id { get; set; }
    public string St_name { get; set; }
    public string St_guardian_name { get; set; }
    public string St_guardian_relation { get; set; }
    public string St_guardian_contact { get; set; }
    public string St_address { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime St_dob { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> St_cl_fk_id { get; set; }
    public int St_status { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Attendence> Attendences { get; set; }
    public virtual Class Class { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Create Action in the StudentsController. PopulateClassDropDown is a helper method.

```
 private void PopulateClassDropDownList(object selectedClass = null)
    {
        var classQuery = from c in db.Classes
                         where c.Cl_status==1
                               select c;
        ViewBag.classID = new SelectList(classQuery, "Cl_id", "Cl_name", selectedClass);
    }
    [Authorize]

    // GET: Students/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        PopulateClassDropDownList();
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Students/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "St_id,St_name,St_guardian_name,St_guardian_relation,St_guardian_contact,St_address,St_dob,St_cl_fk_id.St_status")] Student student)
    {
        try
        {
            var temp = student.St_cl_fk_id;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                student.St_status = 1;
                db.Students.Add(student);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (RetryLimitExceededException /* dex*/ )
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
        }


        PopulateClassDropDownList(student.St_cl_fk_id);

        return View(student);
    }
```

And finally here is the Create View of Student.

```
@model GMASchoolProject.Models.Student

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Site.css">


<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">Create New Student</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Fill in Details
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <form class="col-lg-6" role="form">

                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin:15px;">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.St_name, "Student Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                <div>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.St_name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.St_name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group" style="margin:15px;">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.St_guardian_name, "Name of Guardian", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label " })
                                <div>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.St_guardian_name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.St_guardian_name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin:15px;">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.St_guardian_relation, "Guardian's Relation", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                <div>
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.St_guardian_relation, new[] {
                                                                                   new SelectListItem() {Text="Parents", Value="Parents" },
                                                                                   new SelectListItem() {Text="Other", Value="Other" }
                                    },"Choose an option", new { @class = "form-control" })

                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.St_guardian_relation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin:15px;">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.St_guardian_contact, "Guardian's Contact", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                <div>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.St_guardian_contact, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.St_guardian_contact, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin:15px;">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.St_address, "Student's Address", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                <div>
                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model=>model.St_address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.St_address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin:15px;">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.St_dob, "Student's Date of Birth", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                <div>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.St_dob, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.St_dob, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin:15px;">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ClassID">Class</label>
                                <div>
                                   @Html.DropDownList("classID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.St_cl_fk_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group" style="margin:15px,0,15px,0;">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-2">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-dropdownlist-dropdownlistfor), make these changes:

```
// classId implies a scalar value, this should be a list
ViewBag.classList = new SelectList(classQuery, "Cl_id", "Cl_name", selectedClass);

// Change your dropdown code:
@Html.DropDownList("St_cl_fk_id", (SelectList)ViewBag.classList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
// or better yet:
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.St_cl_fk_id, (SelectList)ViewBag.classList, new { @class = "form-control" })

// remove this line - it should bind automatically
var temp = student.St_cl_fk_id;
```

Comment: When I use DropDownList helper I recieve the following error
 CS1973: 'HtmlHelper<Student>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownList' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: somewhat same thing with DropDownListFor

 CS1928: 'HtmlHelper<Student>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and the best extension method overload 'SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, object)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: My bad, you need to cast the viewbag into a selectlist. See modified code.